# The output that I got in Jupyter is not same as in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, spyder

I wrote a script in Jupyter that is attached. At the end , output is requested two table side by side as below

[image]

Although I got the result in Jupyter, when I run same program in Spyder, I couldn’t get the same result. Is there a way to do it in Spyder?

PS: The files have been token from [kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/olistbr/brazilian-ecommerce):

> To run this script you need only `product_category_name_english.csv` , `olist_products_dataset.csv` and `olist_order_items_dataset.csv` data files

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, HTML

def Problem(file_name1, file_name2, file_name3):

    product_category = pd.read_csv(file_name1, sep=",")  
    product_category.head()
    olist_products = pd.read_csv(file_name2, sep=",")
    olist_products.head()
    olist_order = pd.read_csv(file_name3, sep=",")
    olist_order.head()
    data = pd.merge(pd.merge(product_category, olist_products), olist_order)
    data["freight_percent"] = (data["freight_value"]/(data["freight_value"]+data["price"]))*100
    Data_Categorized = data.pivot_table(index="product_category_name_english", values=(["freight_percent"]), aggfunc="mean")
    top_10 = Data_Categorized.sort_values("freight_percent",  ascending=False)[:10]
    top_10 = top_10.reset_index()
    top_10.index = top_10.index+1
    bottom_10 = Data_Categorized.sort_values("freight_percent")[:10]
    bottom_10 = bottom_10.reset_index()
    bottom_10.index = bottom_10.index+1
    result = pd.concat([top_10, bottom_10], axis=1, sort=False)
    print("\t\t\033[94m\033[1mTOP 10  \t\t\t\t BOTTOM 10")
    display (result)

Problem("product_category_name_translation.csv","olist_products_dataset.csv","olist_order_items_dataset.csv")
```

Comment: What's wrong with the Spyder output?

Comment: Stop stuffing multiple statements onto the same line. Also, those `head` calls are pointless.

Comment: @prashantrana: I have approved your edit. However, please do not add quote blocks for things that are not quotes - that is intended to highlight something that is in the voice of another person/speech/book/manual, etc.

Comment: @halfer thanks. i will remember that .

Comment: @DylanSmith Spyder output doesn’t display as jupyter , I want to display two df side by side therefore I used the concat in my script. If I want to display two df separately spyder runs well , my aim is to show two df in one line side by side

Comment: You might have to use a different method for outputting your result. Spyder and Jupyter are fairly different in a few ways; maybe try just printing the result to the console, or outputting it as a spreadsheet of its own. Or, if you just want to look at it in Spyder, use the Variable Explorer tab and open your dataframe...